# Saving to file system and smart card

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, smartcard, savefiledialog

We have a Windows Forms C# application that allows the user to save data to the file system.  Another portion of the program allows the user to save data directly to a smart card.  With the `SaveFileDialog`, is there any way to provide a smart card reader as an additional save option?  I'm trying to avoid having to use a `MessageBox` to determine which storage medium to use to save the data to.

Comment: You are really talking about a smart card? Not an SD card or something similar? Since the interface is **very** different (no simple *mass storage*), I doubt, that it can be addressed using a standard dialog. What if you have to enter a PIN to acquire the access right for writing the file? Besides that, smart cards are not exactly cheap and offer comparatively little memory, so I don't recognize the benefit.

Comment: Yes @guidot, I'm talking about a smart card. The application requires a PIN to access the card in the first place.  It's an existing application that has a specific need and certain customers prefer the security that saving to the smart card brings but others like the simplicity and flexibility of the password encrypted file.  I'm just looking to see if it is possible to have the smart card readers visible as one of the storage locations so that I can have a singular form to save to.

Comment: You should create your own dialog and let user choose whether to store the file in Windows or in smart card. For sure, you need to check the maximum data that can be absorb by the card... usually only kilobytes, but some special card can also do megabytes. You need to also familiarize how the send the data to the card in parts if it is larger than single APDU.